# Autocompletion (content assist) for XSD files in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD file in Eclipse using the text editor (I'm don't like using  graphical "editors" such as the XML or Schema builder GUIs). For java files Eclipse has a nice auto completion mechanism, but for XSD files, Eclipse seems no more intelligent than notepad. No autocompletion, no suggestions and not assistance at all.

How can I get Eclipse content assist for XSD files in the text editor? Something like the intellisense mechanism in Visual Studio 2010 (which is a joy to write XSD files in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the XML Editor from Eclipse Webtool project. It has source editing with autocompletion, validation and most features you'd want. 
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/

Its available from the main Indigo update site 
`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/`

Comment: It seems that this XML editor was already installed. I didn't see the "Source" tab at the bottom of the editor. It works!